# Do I have to create a new object to mix in a Scala trait?

Tags: scala, traits

In Scala, calling `groupBy()` on a collection returns a `Map` where the values are collections, but I want a `MultiMap`.  What's the easiest way to do the conversion?  Can I avoid creating a new `MultiMap` and copying everything over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer to "Do I have to create a new object to mix in a Scala trait?" is "Yes".  You can minimize the pain some with wrapping objects and implicit conversions.

---

For your specific problem, I was unable to coerce groupBy(...) to return a mutable map to mutable sets, which you would need to wrap it with "MapProxy with MultiMap".  But, it is not too many lines of code to implement your own version of "groupBy":

```
package blevins.example

object App extends Application {

  implicit def multiMapable[B](c: Iterable[B]) = new {
    def groupByMM[A](f: B => A) = {
      import scala.collection.mutable._
      val ret = new HashMap[A,Set[B]] with MultiMap[A,B]
      for (e <- c) { ret.addBinding(f(e), e) }
      ret
    } 
  }

  val c = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
  val mm = c.groupByMM { i => if (i < 5) "alpha" else "beta" }
  mm.addBinding("alpha",12)
  println(mm) // Map(beta -> Set(5, 7, 6, 9, 8), alpha -> Set(3, 1, 4, 2, 12))

}
```

---

**Addendum**

Here is an example of wrapping an existing Map[String,Set[Int]] into a MultiMap without copying the values:

```
object App extends Application {
  import scala.collection.mutable._
  val seed: Map[String,Set[Int]] = Map("even" -> Set(2,4,6), "odd" -> Set(1,3,5))

  val multiMap = new MapProxy[String,Set[Int]] with MultiMap[String,Int] {
    val self = seed
  }

  multiMap.addBinding("even", 8)
  println(multiMap) // Map(odd -> Set(5, 3, 1), even -> Set(6, 8, 4, 2))
}
```

Note that this cannot be done on the result of groupBy(...) because the seed map is required to be mutable and groupBy(...) returns an immutable map.

Comment: Calling groupBy() and a mutable collection does return a mutable.Map.

Comment: Can you demonstrate groupBy returning a mutable Map?  I get a compiler error like shown here (http://gist.github.com/245062).

Comment: I guess it returns an immutable map of mutable sets?  Regardless, I don't want a map at all, I want a multimap.

Comment: The mutability of the result of groupBy(...) is relevant because wrapping it to create a "MapProxy with MultiMap" without copying the values requires it be mutable.  See appended code in answer.

Comment: Thank you, the addendum is exactly the info I was looking for.